# How to fix CORS issues in Chome with WebAudio processed from video?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, web-audio-api

I'm coding a Web App in react that deal with video collections.
The video files are in another server and this server has CORS proper configured. So all works fine playing videos.

The issue now is that I'm implementing some features to see the Audio levels using the WebAudio API.

The problem is that, once I use `this.source = AudioContext.createMediaElementSource(VideoSrc);`, to get the video as source, the Chrome console shows: `MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for https://...`.

I tried both `this.source.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials';` and `this.source.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';`. I doesn't matter.

This only happens in Chrome, Firefox works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.  You should file a bug at http://crbug.com/new with the repro case.

Comment: What does the remote server that hosts the video includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response to the preflight `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis - it shows the url where my webapp is running

Comment: @DanielMiclos: maybe you can post it here? The header should actually contain only the domain, not the full url (not sure if Firefox and Chrome treat such responses differently), also do the schemes match (the error in your post has `https` does the header have `https` as well?).

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis - my mistake, I mean the domain. An yes, the schemes are different, the video server is https, but my app is local http. Anyway, is something that just Chrome rejects.

Comment: @DanielMiclos - according to the rfc, it is correct to reject a domain with different scheme. Can you fix the schemes?

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis - Since it's an internal domain, I have to check with the guys who deal with the network. Maybe they will reply my open issue in less than a year!